# vim error grep: env: No such file or directory grep: LANG/: No such file or directory grep: */main.aap: No such file or directory

Tags: vim

I am seeing some issue vim 9.0 version, not really sure whats causing the issue, whenever I try opening any file, I bumped with this below stuf from vim:

```
:!grep -n /sys env LANG/ */main.aap /dev/null | tee /tmp/vTzBCpI/0
grep: env: No such file or directory
grep: LANG/: No such file or directory
grep: */main.aap: No such file or directory
```

After pressing enter just before the file contents are buffered in I see another annoying notification:

```
Everything appears to be OK
Done
No duplicate words found
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Any clue whats causing this issue, I have been using all my life but unfortunately not an expert at configs, this kind of weird issue which is not going away even though have tried re-install and all.

Comment: You have an alias or something, somewhere, that explicitly does all those things. Maybe you merged two files that shouldn't be merged together? Hard to tell without being in font of your keyboard. See if you can reproduce the errors with `$ vim -Nu NONE` and/or `$ vim --clean`.

Comment: Both ```$ vim -Nu NONE``` & ```$ vim --clean``` had no issues. Have tried re-installing the vim packages using apt but still hitting same issue

Comment: "Both `$ vim -Nu NONE` & `$ vim --clean` had no issues." I those had no issues then the problem is not related to Vim itself but to your config. That's where you need to look.